# Syntax error executing stored procedure in openrowset with parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to store the result of a stored procedure in a temp table, therefore I have to call it using `OPENROWSET` however when executing the query

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)      

DECLARE @callToProc nvarchar(255)
SET @callToProc =  'EXEC dbo.mySpName @param1=' + CAST ( 1 AS nvarchar(200) ) + ', @param2= ''Achat'' ' 

SET @sql =  'SELECT * INTO #mytempTab FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=myserv;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', ' + @callToProc + ') AS myalias'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

I get the following error :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

But I really don't see what is wrong with my request

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not the right way of doing it. Try something like this. This method can employed if you **don't** know the no. of columns returned by the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @callToProc NVARCHAR(255)

SET @callToProc = '''EXEC dbo.sp_RecupererMontantLegsParRunSoitVenteSoitAchat @IdRun='+ Cast ( 1 AS NVARCHAR(200) )+ ', @TypeLeg= ''''Achat'''''' '

SET @sql = 'SELECT * INTO #mytempTab FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=myserv;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', '
           + @callToProc + ') AS myalias'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

**NOTE :** To `debug dynamic sql` always **`print`** the the dynamic sql before executing which will give you an idea of what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem (quotation marks were missing). However I also realize that I should use the method provided by Andy Korneyev since I know the columns returned by my SP. Thanks a lot for the tip about debugging dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using `OPENROWSET` at all.

Just create your temp table having the same quantity, order and types of columns as your stored procedure returns, and then just insert into it like this:

```
create table #myTempTable ( columns definitions here)

insert into #mytempTab
exec dbo.mySpName
    @Param1 = ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll move toward this approach.